# Groovy map syntax error

Tags: groovy, dictionary, syntax-error

If I have this code :

```
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.image.*

def xMap = [
    BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR     : "3 byte BGR",
    BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR    : "4 byte ABGR",
]
```

the IDE will generate this error :

```
illegal colon after argument expression;
   solution: a complex label expression before a colon must be parenthesized at
```

Is there another solution to this than to write :

```
def type_3byte_bgr = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR
```

for all the constants?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Map literals require their keys to be valid identifiers or in parentheses. This should work:

```
def xMap = [
    (BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)     : "3 byte BGR",
    (BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR)    : "4 byte ABGR",]
```

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 5):

The error message tells you how to solve it: parenthesize the label expression.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage

def xMap = [
    (BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)     : "3 byte BGR",
    (BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR)    : "4 byte ABGR",
]

println xMap[BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR]
```

Comment: Control your language please.

Comment: @Michael I am getting (groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: spring for class: groovy.lang.Binding) error when I try to do 
def d = [(spring.profiles.active): 'e2e']